# Show that $f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $(\mathbb{R}, +, \tau_{\mathbb{R}})$ and $(\mathbb{S}^1, \cdot, \tau_{\mathbb{S}^1})$ be a topological groups, where $\tau_{\mathbb{R}}$ is the usual topology of real numbers and $\tau_{\mathbb{S}^1}$ is the subspace topology induced by $\mathbb{C}^*$ with the open ball topology.

I need proof that the homomorphism $f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$, given by $f(x) = \cos(2\pi x) + i\sin(2\pi x) $ is continuous but I still didn't get it. I thought about using a result that says that the homomorphism will be continuous if and only if it is continuous on the neutral element, but I didn't succeed.

Do you suggest any Theorem of complex analysis or some composition of functions that will help me to get around this problem?

Comment: That depends on how you define the complex exponential function. Generally this is basics of complex analysis.

Comment: In a good book about complex analysis, they should prove that $z\mapsto \exp(z)$ is a continuous map. Then $f$ is just a simple composition of continuous functions.

Comment: Do you know how to characterize continuous functions into a subspace topology, in general?

Comment: Here's a geometric hint: can you show that if the angle between two points is small, then the chord between them is small?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the function $f$ as a function from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb C$. Then $f=\exp\circ g$, where $g\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ is the function defined by $g(x)=2\pi ix$. Then $f$ is continuous, since it is obtained from two continuous functions by composition.

Since $f$ is a continuous function from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb C$, since the range of $f$ is a subset of $\Bbb S^1$, and since the topology that you are taking into account in $\Bbb S^1$ is the subspace topology, $f$ is a continuous function from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb S^1$.

Comment: Objection, $g$ is not a function into $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Jakobian I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Honestly, that answer is pretty much "it is continuous because it is". Unless the OP didn't notice that it is a composition of linear map with exp?

Comment: @freakish Actually, I think that the OP failed to notice that in order to prove that $f$ is continuous, all that needs to be done is to prove that it is continuous as a map from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @freakish I agree, but it's really more of a fault of the OP because their question is ambiguous in what they mean rather than this answer's fault.

Comment: As an alternative to the comments and answer that refer to the complex exponential function, this result also follows from the fact that if $f, g : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ are continuous functions, then so is $x \mapsto (f(x), g(x)) : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R}$.